# Ajax menu for PHP query

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**UPDATED**

Have now got this far with this and think I am getting stuck right at the end!!
I have now got both menus being processed by "process.php" and am outputting my queries back into index.php.

process.php

```html
<?php
$menu1 = $_POST["menu1"];
$menu2 = $_POST["menu2"];

if($menu1 == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Language WHERE ID = " . $menu2;   
} else if($menu1 == 1) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Mathematics WHERE ID = " . $menu2;
} else if($menu1 == 2) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Culture WHERE ID = " . $menu2;
}

echo $sql;

?>
```

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
var data = {
   Language:       ["","Noun Game","Phonetic Noun Box"],
   Mathematics:    ["","Number Rods","Sandpaper Numerals"],
   Culture:        ["","Concept of Time-Clock"]
}
// populate menu1
for (var i in data) {
    $('#menu1').append('<option>' + i + '</option>');
}
// populate menu2 based on menu1 value
$('#menu1').change(function() {
    var key = $(this).val();
    $('#menu2').empty();
    for (var i in data[key]) {
        $('#menu2').append('<option>' + data[key][i] + '</option>');
 }
}).trigger('change');
});//]]>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" action="process.php" method="post">
  <select id="menu1" name="menu1"></select>
  <select id="menu2" name="menu2"></select>

 <input id="submit" type="submit" value="ENTER" />
 
</form>
<div id="resultsContainer"></div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       //alert('jQuery loaded');
        $('#form').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault;
            menu1value = $('#menu1')[0].selectedIndex;
            menu2value = $('#menu2')[0].selectedIndex;
            $.post('process.php',{menu1:menu1value,menu2:menu2value}).done(function(data){
                alert(data);
            })
            return false;
        })
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I just need to output queries in a table on index.php.
Think this will be just about looping through the output but I'm not sure...
any help please.

Comment: correct my if I'm wrong, you have menu1 and menu2, and you want to run a query using ajax based on menu1 and menu2 values?

Comment: No I am using ajax to populate the menus. This is part of a php webpage and I am looking to use menu1 and menu2 to select data from different tables in a mySQL database!

Comment: Sorry, in that case, I still have not understand what is your problem or question. do you have question regarding to how to make your query using menu1 and menu2 values?

Comment: Yes I am unable to work out how to use the values that are set in menu1 and menu2 to create my queries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to populate both of the selects using ajax.

That said your script will probably be similar to this:

```
$('#menu1').ajax({
type: "POST",
cashe: false,
url: 'processing-page.php',
success: function(data){
// use data to make the options
}
});

    $('#menu2').on('click', function(){
.ajax({
type: "post",
cashe: false,
url: 'processing-page.php',
data: {val1: Val1, val2: Val2},
success: function(data){
// make options with the data
}
});
});
```

You will have to create a separate php page that will query the database and send results back through ajax.

Sorry it looks kind of weird.  I typed it in on a phone.  Let me know if this works for you or if anything needs clarification.

**UPDATE:**
This is the only way I know how to return multiple values (such as queries) using ajax.  In the processing page I format the queries into a string to send back.
processing-page.php:

```
<?php
switch ($_POST["menu1"]) {
  case "Language":
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
    $result4 = mysql_query($sql4); 
    break;
  case "Mathematics":
    // and so on...
    break;
  }
}

$allResults = array($result1, $result2, $result3, $result4);
$allResultStr = "";  
// make the queries into strings  
foreach($allResults as $result){
  $allResultStr = $allResultStr . $result[key1] ."|". $result[key2] . ",";
}  
$allResultStr = substr($optionArray, 0, -1); // takes the last comma off  
echo $allResultStr;
?>
```

In the script, I take apart the string using the `split()` function.
Javascript:

```
function(data){  // data is $allResultStr
  var options = data.split(",");
  for(var option in options){
    var parts = options[option].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    // make the option values and text based on the results
    newOption.value = parts[0]; 
    newOption.innerHTML = parts[1];
    document.getElementById("#menu2").options.add(newOption);
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess so I have 5 options in menu 1 and between 25 and 45 in menu 2.

Comment: I  have 20 tables in the database 4 for each item in menu 1 so when I pick a category like maths I need to make 4 searches for a selection from menu 2. so if I pick maths and number rods I return 4 separate query's back to the page.

Comment: So you have to use `switch` or `if` and create different queries regarding your menu selection combinations. of course you have to create one query with two parameters and in your `switch` or `if` depending on the condition, fill two parameters with correct values(the can be table names or field names).

Comment: Sorry I did not answer your question before.  I have updated my answer.  Hopefully this better answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I'm trying to make sense of this